# Java enums mapping?

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums which have a mapping between them.

Enum1:

```
public enum HttpMethodName 
{
    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE; 
}
```

Enum2:

```
public enum ProtocolOperation {
    CREATE(1), RETRIEVE(2), UPDATE(3), DELETE(4), NOTIFY(5);


    private BigInteger operationId;

    public BigInteger getOperationId() {
        return operationId;
    }

    private ProtocolOperation(int operationId) {
        this.operationId = BigInteger.valueOf(operationId);
    }
}
```

The enums values have mapping as:

```
Create--> POST
Retrieve--> GET
Update--> PUT
Delete--> DELETE
Notify---> POST
```

**One way** of providing the mapping will be to create a **third** enum by the name of binder:

Enum 3:

```
CREATE(1, HttpMethodName.POST),
    RETRIEVE(2, HttpMethodName.GET),
    UPDATE(3, HttpMethodName.PUT),
    DELETE(4, HttpMethodName.DELETE),
    NOTIFY(5, HttpMethodName.POST);
```

Other way is to keep two enums only and  modify the Enum2 itself to have the mapping.

Which approach will be better ??

I feel in approach1 there will be separation though I feel third enum is not a constant type (which is the main purpose of an enum), it will be a binder.

One caveat is there may be more bindings coming up as the code grows. For ex for another type of protocol there may be a second binding with respect to `CREATE`, etc.

Comment: If possible bindings may increase in future then you should consider it as an entity. Please explain a bit more about this possible binding. i.e. CREATE will be binding with what?

Comment: Adding the binding using a method gives you the flexibilty of adding any logic later, check my answer.

Comment: @BilboBaggins: So there can be some other protocol whose value may be associated with `CREATE`. Ex: `CREATE(1, HttpMethodName.POST, SomeOtheProtocol.SOME_NAME)`

Comment: Wouldn't keeping three enums two separte types and one binder be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a public method `getHttpMethod()` (that will handle the mapping) to `ProtocolOperation` like this:

```
public enum ProtocolOperation {

    CREATE(1){
        @Override
        public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName(){
            return HttpMethodName.POST; 
        }
    },
    RETRIEVE(2){
        @Override
        public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName(){
            return HttpMethodName.GET;  
        }
    },
    UPDATE(3){
        @Override
        public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName(){
            return HttpMethodName.PUT;  
        }
    },
    DELETE(4){
        @Override
        public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName(){
            return HttpMethodName.DELETE;   
        }
    },
    NOTIFY(5){
        @Override
        public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName(){
            return HttpMethodName.POST; 
        }
    };


    private BigInteger operationId;


    public BigInteger getOperationId() {
        return operationId;
    }

    private ProtocolOperation(int operationId) {
        this.operationId = BigInteger.valueOf(operationId);
    }

   abstract public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName();
}
```

---

e.g

```
ProtocolOperation createProtocolOperation = ProtocolOperation.CREATE;
HttpMethodName createOpHttpMethodName = createProtocolOperation.getHttpMethodName();
```

Comment: So if a new binding comes (Please check my above comment), I will have to add a new method for each ?

Comment: Yeah that what we do in my company. It seems tidious the first time but it will soon start payin off.

Comment: Wouldn't keeping three enums two separte types and one binder be a good idea?

Comment: why? This is an implication that one Protocol enum can act differently on d/t times, and this is clear scenario for adding behaviours(methods) to the Protocol